# how can I draw a rectangle and circle/ellipse in WPF like we do in paint by dragging mouse

Tags: wpf, canvas, drawing, mouse, whiteboard

I am developing a whiteboard application in WPF.

How can I draw a rectangle and circle/ellipse by dragging the mouse like we do in Paint by dragging the mouse pointer ?

I am using WPF canvas for drawing.

Answer (score 2):

have a look into below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools

Comment: I can't run that project. I am getting ~400 errors in "DrawToolsLib" class library

Comment: getting error symbol in this assemblies "WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework"

Comment: add these refrances from dot.net refrances. which version of visual studio you are using.

Comment: tried that it didnt worked

ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820241/error-project-file-must-include-the-net-framework-assembly-windowsbase-prese

Comment: which version visual studio and which framework you are using.?

Answer (score 1):

To run WPF-DrawTools you have to:

1. Let the VS to convert the project.
2. Set appropriate NetFramework version (say, Net 4.5).
3. Add references to correspondent libraries (e.g., PresentationCore) if VS could not find them itself.